# Instagram API to get Users Demographics(Age, Country)

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api, instaloader

I'm working on a research project which needs some information on user demographics. Is there an instagram API(paid or opensource) that I can use to get users demographics(Age, Gender, Country) in instagram?

I tried instaloader which is pretty good but it doesn't provide any demographics information. I also looked into Instagram Graph API, it doesn't seem to provide either.
Given a username, I would like to get users gender, age, country if available

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.